# How to refresh the same page in React when clicking the same page link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way that every time you click on a Link in React refreshes the page? even if you are on the same page that the Link is taking you, so the user can refresh the page.

For example, I have an icon that takes to "/" the main page, and that Icon is also on the footer. When I am on the bottom of the home page and I click it does not refresh the page so I am still at the bottom of the page.

I am using this code to restore the scroll position every time I go to another tab

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

but that only restore the home position when changing page.

This is my code:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
        <ScrollToTop />
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar></Navbar>
      <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<Home></Home>} ></Route>
      <Route  path='/movies/:id' element={<MovieDetails ></MovieDetails>} ></Route>
      <Route  path='/user' element={<UserPage></UserPage>} ></Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer></Footer>
      </div>
    </Router>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a prop called `forceRefresh` which you can use to resolve your query.

You have to use this `prop` in the `Router` tag.

Like this

```
Router forceRefresh={true}
```

Overall you main `jsx` should look like this.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router forceRefresh={true}>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/movies/:id" element={<MovieDetails />} />
          <Route path="/user" element={<UserPage />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you want to refresh a specific `Route` then use this prop in the associated `Link` tag of the specific `Route`.

```
<Link to="/that_route" reloadDocument> That Route </Link>
```

Comment: Is there a way to only force the refresh on a per-`Link` basis? This would be a bit of an over-the-top solution in many cases

Comment: yes I have edited the answer check.

Comment: With this solution I don't even need the <ScrollToTop /> because is now taking me always to the top of the page